# Run phantomjs and casperjs on local folder

Tags: npm, phantomjs, local, casperjs, require

I'm looking for a solution about one problem. I want to install and use the library casperjs without install anything globally on the machine.

First i try to install just by `npm install casperjs` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/casperjs)

Obviously, this is the error message : `casperjs : commande introuvable`

I try to use static path : `../../node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs scriptCasperJS.js`

New error : `Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?`

So i download and extract phantomjs from [website](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and export my folder to the environment variable : `export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/home/xxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs`

It's okay but new error : `CasperError: Can't find module casperjs`

This probably come from my code :

```
var casper = require("casperjs").create({    
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: "debug"
});
```

Any idea ..? Do i must change the way to code with casperjs ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT : for better understanding

```
- myfolder
   +- modules
   |  +- phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
   |  | +- bin
   |  | | +- phantomjs 
   +- node_modules
   |  +- casperjs    
   |  | +- bin
   |  | | +- casperjs    
   +- scripts
   |  +- myscriptname   
   |  | +- scriptCasperJS.js   
   +- package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: It seems I misunderstood your problem. Here's the new answer:**

To include the Casper module in a script ran by casperJS, the correct require is

```
var casper = require("casper"); // Not "casperjs" !
```

Old answer:

CasperJS is *not* a NodeJS module. It is clearly specified in their doc. (See the red warning at the bottom of the section : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-npm).

The NPM install is provided for convenience only. You won't be able to do a require, but only call it as an external command.

Comment: I'm aware of that, my script is running via this command like i said : `../../node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs scriptCasperJS.js`

Previously, casper was installed globally (-g) and everything running well.

Comment: Well, in this case, the answer is even more simple. It's just a wrong require, I just checked it. :- )

Comment: Okay ! So it's work... Wonderfull !! But where the fu** did you find this tips ?!

Of course I thank you but maybe the "gaterie" will wait ;-)

Comment: It's in the doc : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html ;)
(Plus, usually, I tend to add or remove the "js" part in a require. Works 99% of the time.)